# Reveal hidden div via slideToggle without pushing down other divs

Tags: media-queries, slidetoggle, css

I ran into this issue while building my online design portfolio. It seems complex to me, but I know there is a way to do it, so I am frustrated that I can't find a solution. Please help!

My design calls for the use of media queries to optimize my site for mobile, tablets, and desktops/laptops. The mobile version has a single column of thumbnails. When each thumbnail is clicked, a hidden div is revealed below it via jQuery slideToggle, pushing down the other project thumbnails.

That is how the mobile version works and it works great. The problem is the tablet and dektop/laptop versions. For those versions, I want the the thumbnails to display in a grid pattern. Two side-by-side on tablets and three side-by-side on desktop/laptops with infinite rows for all versions. I can make them display in a grid with HTML, but the problem comes when a thumbnail is clicked and it reveals the div below it via slideToggle. Since I'm using media queries, the order of the HTML is still the same as the mobile version and the hidden divs are directly below each thumbnail in the code. Thus, revealing the hidden div pushes down all the other thumbnails, including the thumbnails in the same row as the thumbnail that is being clicked (if they come after it in the code). The last div in each row does what I want it to; the next row is pushed down when the hidden div is revealed. I want the hidden div to display below the row it is in and push down the thumbnails that are in the rows below.

And obviously I want to stick with media queries to avoid creating separate HTML, if possible.

**Repeating HTML for the thumbnails and hidden divs:**

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="projectWrapper"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="projectWrapper"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="projectWrapper"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="projectWrapper"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
</div>
```

**I created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem:** http://jsfiddle.net/EuHyc/13/

Please note that the divs are hidden using jQuery. Hiding them with CSS was not allowing my content within the hidden div to display properly when revealed. Also, I had to use display:inline-block because float:left does not force the hidden div to appear below it in the layout.

I hope I adequately explained the problem. Thanks in advance for any help! I sincerely appreciate it!